# How to find opencv-contrib-python version compatible with Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using instructions that I found on PyImageSearch ([here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/)) to install Open CV on a brand new Raspberry Pi3 Buster O/S, but I'm running into problems finding a version of opencv-contrib-python that satisfies the version requirements.  Here is a list of all commands issued.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
python3 -m venv .opencv
source .opencv/bin/activate
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-103
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-test python3-pyqt5
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev
sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
```

Upon issuing the last command, I get the failure "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement..."  I have tried using the latest version 4.5.2.54 with the same result.  The latest version of Buster comes with Python 3.7.3.

I suspect the PyImageSearch site is just out of date.  Is this just a matter of finding the correct version, or am I just doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a user's post on the PyImageSearch web site.  The solution is to install the latest version of pip as follows.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```